# Как узнать текущую абсолютную ширину столбца у Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Есть такой код

```
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="col1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="col2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="text1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <GridSplitter Width="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="text2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=col1,Path=Width}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=col2,Path=Width}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Если положить это в форму и запустить, то будет видно, что значение ширины столбцов меняется при перетаскивании сплиттера, но оно со звездочкой (то есть относительное). `ActualWidth` при этом равен 0. Как мне в таком случае узнать настоящий абсолютный размер столбцов таблицы?

Comment: У вас биндинг на `Width`, а не `ActualWidth`.

Comment: @Discord, я знаю. Так и задумано. Внимательнее читайте

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще узнавать его ширину? Почему просто не сделать `Grid.Column="0"`? Может объясните что хотите сделать?

Comment: @Donil, меня не устраивает штатная `SharedSizeGroup`, я сделаю свою систему уравнивания размеров.

Answer (score 1):

Решил так. Добавил в нужную ячейку невидимый `Border`, растянутый по нужному размеру (ширина или высота). И уже его `ActualWidth` соответствует реальному размеру ячейки.